# Use SignalR hub to connect to another SignalR hub

Tags: asp.net, signalr

I have a website that has SignalR hub, in this hub I need to connect to another SignalR hub which is also hosted in a website.

```
public FirstHub : Hub, IDisconnect
{

  public void FirstMethod()
     ///Connect to second hub in the second website.
     HubConnection hubConnection = new HubConnection("http://localhost:1234");
     IHubProxy firstHub = hubConnection.CreateProxy("SecondWebSite.SecondHub");
     firstHub.On("secondCallBack", i =>
           {
               Caller.showMessage("Ok, Website 2 has return message");
           });

     hubConnection.Start().Wait();
     firstHub.Invoke("SecondMethod").ContinueWith(task =>
           {
               Caller.showMessage(task.Exception.Message);   
           }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
}
```

in the second website I have this hub :

```
public class SecondHub : Hub, IDisconnect
    {
        public void SecondMethod()
        {
            Caller.callBack("Yes, I got it");
        }
}
```

in the first website I have this javascript code

```
var firstHub = $.connection.firstHub;
 $.connection.hub.start({ transport: 'auto' }, function () {
        alert('connected');
    });
$('#TestButton').click(function () {
        firstHub.firstMethod();

firstHub.showMessage = function (msg) {
     alert(msg);
};
```

now when I open the page i see the message (connected), but when I press the test button,
I get nothing !!
and there is no error in the fire-bug console.
but sometimes, I don't know how is this happen, when I step into the code and start debugging, the browse shows the message (Ok, Website 2 has return message).

I couldn't figure out what is happening !!
is this idea possible ?? am I missing something ???

I got these lines in the output window :

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in System.Web.dll
Failed to process message: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ThreadContext.Enter(Boolean setImpersonationContext)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.OnThreadEnterPrivate(Boolean setImpersonationContext)
   at System.Web.AspNetSynchronizationContext.CallCallbackPossiblyUnderLock(SendOrPostCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.AspNetSynchronizationContext.CallCallback(SendOrPostCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.AspNetSynchronizationContext.Post(SendOrPostCallback callback, Object state)
   at SignalR.Client.Connection.OnReceived(String message) in D:\TestProjects\SignalR\SignalR.Client\Connection.cs:line 188
   at SignalR.Client.Transports.HttpBasedTransport.OnMessage(Connection connection, String response) in D:\TestProjects\SignalR\SignalR.Client\Transports\HttpBasedTransport.cs:line 139
```

Comment: BTW, when I use the same code in the first hub, in a Windows application it works just fine !!!!

Comment: Actually, I'm making website that will communicate with a WCF web-service, this web-service has also a hub for notifying subscribers with some changes. and It's also used by another applications (including windows application).

Comment: Guys !! you didn't tell me, this a bug :( !!! , look like someone else has the same problem !! https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/221 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9541561/signalr-net-client-cannot-start-connection-from-within-web-application-app-dom/9542292#9542292

Comment: Looks like David Fowler fixed the bug.  Does the latest version on nuget fix your issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@dfowler
Ok, as I said in the comments, it was a bug in SignalR and it is solved now.
and also my problem is solved.
  Thanks David ,
Thanks everybody, you're awesome.
here are links to relevant topics.

[SignalR .NET Client: Cannot Start Connection From Within Web Application App Domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9541561/signalr-net-client-cannot-start-connection-from-within-web-application-app-dom/9542292#9542292)

https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/221